# Group rows by several values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sum, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe df like this:

```
AgeGroup    Number  Percent
0   0-4     229     1.0
1   15-19   127     1.0
2   20-24   242     1.0
3   25-44   2348    9.0
4   45-64   7063    29.0
5   5-14    144     1.0
6   65-74   4750    19.0
7   75-84   5670    23.0
8   85plus  4198    17.0
9   AllAges 24771   100.0
```

I wish I was able to group these values into broader age groups, for example, I have tried to group ages '0-4'and '5-14' together like this.

```
df.loc[(df.AgeGroup == '0-4') & (df.AgeGroup == '5-14'), 'Number'].sum()
#or,
df.query("AgeGroup == '0-4' and AgeGroup == '5-14'")['Number'].sum()
```

The above gives value 0 showing zero rows.

however, this works for one value giving 1 row.

```
df.query('AgeGroup == "5-14"')
```

```
5   5-14        144     1.0
```

How can I amend it so it showed two rows?

Comment: There query is not being processed because you are using an AND condition. There are no 2 entries that are '0-4' AND '5-14'. Have you tried changing it to an OR?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `AgeGroup` that satisfies the **AND** condition:

```
(df.AgeGroup == '0-4') & (df.AgeGroup == '5-14')
```

do you mean **OR**:

```
(df.AgeGroup == '0-4') | (df.AgeGroup == '5-14')
```

You can also use `isin`:

```
df.AgeGroup.isin(['0-4', '5-14'])
```